# Typo in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, Exercise 15.30?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, orientation, pullback

Exercise 15.30 (p.389):

Suppose (*M, g*) and ($\tilde{M}, \tilde{g}$) are positive-dimensional Riemannian manifolds with or without boundary, and $ F: M \to \tilde{M}$ is a local isometry.  Show that $ F^*\omega_{\tilde{g}} = \omega_{g}$.

$\omega_{g}$ and $\omega_{\tilde{g}}$ are the Riemannian volume forms on *M* and $\tilde{M}$ - which are assumed to be oriented.  (Evaluated on positively-oriented orthonormal frames, they give a value of +1 on their respective manifolds.)  Shouldn't the above read $ F^*\omega_{\tilde{g}} = \pm\omega_{g}$?  In particular, if *F* is an orientation-reversing local isometry, the volume form on $\tilde{M}$ gets pulled back to the negative of its counterpart on *M* - right?  Or am I missing something in the definitions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're right -- good catch. I've added this to my [correction list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/). Surprised nobody has pointed this out before.

Comment: Great- thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Consider $(\mathbb{R},dx\otimes dx)$. Then $x\mapsto -x$ is an isometry but reverses the orientation.

Some isometries do preserve the orientation. They are called "orientation preserving isometries".